# Error in restoring .bak file to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to restore a backup file to SQL Server 2008. I am getting the following message.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server
>   running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this
>   server, which is running version 10.00.1600. Either restore the
>   database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is
>   compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I need to transfer all data from the SQL server 2008 R2 backup file to SQL server 2008 database.

Can you please suggest me how to restore the .bak file.

Comment: What don't you understand in the error message?

Comment: I tried to but was not clear about SQL Server 2008 and R2.

Comment: You **CANNOT** restore a database backup made on a newer version of SQL Server (2008 R2 - v10.50) in an **older** version of SQL Server (like 2008 = v10.00). This is not (and never has been) supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although SQL 2008 and SQL2008 R2 have similar(ish) names, a backup from SQL 2008R2 (where your .bak file was created) cannot be restored on a SQL 2008 instance (where you are trying to restore it.)

You could create a new backup using a third party tool like Redgate SQLBackup, or you could use the import/export wizard in SSMS to transfer the data, but R2 backups are not backward compatible unfortunately.

Comment: @M_M, I too have a .bak file but dont know how to mport/export wizard in SSMS to transfer the data. Can you throw some light

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay I'd be happy to help, but it may be better to address in a separate question.

Comment: @M_M , thanks mate....I updated the SQL Express 2008 to SQL Express 2008 R2 so was able to import the .bak file...